# Frame IsVisible Binding has no effect

Tags: c#, binding, inotifypropertychanged, maui

I am having an issue with my Binding on isVisible in latest .Net Maui Preview 17.3.0 Preview 2.0. Probably unrelated to the version. I am not using MVVM..here is my code:

```
 <Frame Background="LightBlue" IsVisible="{Binding FrameVisible}" x:Name="Frame_Test" Margin="0,10,0,0" CornerRadius="25" HeightRequest="100">
```

In the backend of the XAML, I have the boolean I am trying to bind to

```
private bool frameVisible;
        public bool FrameVisible
        {
            get
            {
                return frameVisible;
            }
            set
            {
                frameVisible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FrameVisible");
            }
        }
```

I am implementing INotifiyPropertyChanged

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[App] Property changed {propertyName}");
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
```

In my class constructor I am setting bindingcontext = this;
What am I missing? The OnPropertyChanged triggers after changing  frameVisible = false or true but I don't see any changes on GUI for the frame. The result after hovering over Xaml shows No datacontext found for binding.

Comment: `DataContext` is a XAML helper to provide Intellisense, it should not matter at runtime.  Does your class actually implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?  ie `public class MyPageName : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: Yes: public partial class MainPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Testing on Windows or Android? Possibly an issue specific to `Frame`, which is legacy class from X-Forms, so uses different renderer mechanism. Try `Border` instead. Or wrap Frame in a `StackLayout`, bind IsVisible on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IsVisible` is currently bugged and not working unfortunately, seems like a fix has been merged. See: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8044

Comment: Thanks Gerald, helpful as always. I'll keep an eye on current Maui issues if I run into an issue next time.

Answer (score 1):

Use Border instead of Frame. Example:

```
<Border Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" IsVisible="{Binding FrameVisible}" x:Name="Frame_Test">
    <Border.StrokeShape>
        <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="0,0,0,0" />
    </Border.StrokeShape>
    <!-- Object you wish to wrap border around -->
</Border>
```